# c++ Fastest way to write/read array of shorts to/from file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

What is the fastest way to write an array of unsigned short values into a file, and then what would be the fastest way to read these in another application?

Also this would be on an apple machine running snow leopard.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't worry about cross-platform compatibility, just write them all out in binary:

```
int save_shorts(const unsigned short* array, size_t num_shorts)
{
  int ok = 0;
  FILE* out = fopen("numbers.bin", "wb");

  if (out != NULL)
  {
    ok = fwrite(array, num_shorts * sizeof *array, 1, out) == 1;
    fclose(out);
  }
  return ok;
}
```

Reading them back in is very similiar but with `fread()`, of course. You could probably use C++ (binary) streams too, but this is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are about a gazillion approaches to this, starting from simple file I/O to compressing the data in memory under whatever format (zlib?) and then writing it to the file. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't go faster than mapping the file into memory and writing to that memory. This avoids stdio buffering and copying data between user-space and kernel.